# Make DIV 100% with overflow-y

Tags: html, css, styles

I have several DIV elements structure one placed under another.

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="title">Title</div>
    <div id="block1">Block 1</div>
    <div id="block2">Block 2</div>
    <div id="content">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

`#title`, `#block1` and `#block2` have fixed height and I'd like that content will take 100% of free space and also will have `overflow-y: auto` i.e. will have scrollbars when its content doesn't fit.

How can I do it?
I've read about idea of making content absolutely positioned and set its bottom to 0px and its top to summary of other DIVs' heights. However I can have more DIV elements over the content block and don't want to change its CSS all the time.

I have also set:

```
html, body, #app {
    height: 100%
}
```

But when I set `#content` to be 100% height it goes over the bottom of the screen and that's not what i need. I'd like that `#app` will be 100% height and `#content` just fit into it showing scrollbars if needed.

Here is jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ZNFcd/

Any help? Since its intranet app so solutions that work only in chrome + CSS3 solutions are also welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to set `margin:0` and `padding:0` on the `html, body` declaration for starters. You also need to use `box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: This fiddle is slightly closer to what you want http://jsfiddle.net/ZNFcd/1/

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery Option**

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ZNFcd/4/)**

```
var contentHeight = function () {
    var w = $(window).height();
    x = $('#title').height();
    y = $('#block1').height();
    z = $('#block2').height();
    h = w - x - y - z - 3; // -3 to account for borders
    $('#content').height(h);
};

$(document).ready(contentHeight);
$(window).resize(contentHeight);
```

[API documentation for .height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Using a little script for this has the advantage of being a little more flexible. Try adding or removing content or changing the heights on your other divs.

**Pure CSS option**

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ZNFcd/5/)**

```
#app {
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box
}
#title {
    height: 20px;
}
#block1 {
    height: 30px;
}
#block2 {
    height: 40px;
}
#content {
    height: 90%; /* fallback for browsers without support for calc() */
    height: calc(100% - 90px);
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box
}
```

[Documentation for calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
[Documentation for box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

I would go with the jQuery option personally, `calc()` is cool, but its not supported in Opera and is "buggy" in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @apaul34208's CSS solution, you can use

```
html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
#app {
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
#title {
    height: 20px;
}
#block1 {
    height: 30px;
}
#block2 {
    height: 40px;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This way you don't need `calc()`, which doesn't work on old browsers.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MWWgE/)